# remote notification does not launch app in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, apple-push-notifications

I have started experimenting with the new remote notification service in iOS 7. The interesting part, from the documentation is from [UIApplication Delegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_12).

> If your app is suspended or not running, the system wakes up or launches your app and puts it into the background running state before calling the method.

However, when i send a silent remote notification with the key "content-available" and a payload of "1", the app is not launched into background mode.
If my app is in background mode or suspended, the notification is delivered to the app.

Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: Have you added `remote-notification` to your UIBackgroundModes Info PList entry?

Comment: Yes, its added via XCodes new "Capabilities" feature. I have also double checked the file and the key and value is present

Comment: If you send a push with an alert message, do you see the message/is the push received? If not, it suggests that your app isn't launched because there's an issue with push in general.

Comment: If i send a normal alert push, it gets displayed. So regular push is working just fine. I tried rebooting my device and remote notifications wasn't received then either, even though it was present in multitasking menu

Comment: I think apple has wrong documentation.  Please refer apple forum https://devforums.apple.com/message/873265#873265.  According to that remote-notification will work in background/foreground/suspended state. It won't work in "not-running" state.

Comment: I have seen that post, but it seems weird that Apple don't update the documentation. Also, this feature was highlighted in the wwdc talk about multitasking. So if your app has to be running in the background for this to work, it's not that great of a feature.

Comment: It definitely works in not-running, that's the whole point of the feature. You can verify this in a working app by looking at the device console in Xcode's organizer for logs. Note also that you can send a remote notification that isn't silent, i.e. with an alert and a `content-available` value. This will make your debugging a little easier. You might also find my article on [Remote Notifications](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html#remote_notifications) useful.

Comment: @DavidCaunt, I tried by sending remote-notification with alert message.  I am receiving message in the app, however doesn't open the app. I need to tap the received alert to open our app.

Comment: @DavidCaunt I created a new app, a new certificate and the whole routine. It still will not load the app when my app is in a state of not running. So, just to clarify, when you say "not running", what do you actually mean? If you kill your app by using the new multitask menu and swipe up so the app is killed. Do you still receive remote push notifications? And does iOS still wake up your app and let it execute code?

Comment: As I understand it, if you swipe up, iOS infers that the user doesn't want that app to multitask, and remote notifications *will not* work. If you stop the app with Xcode, and then send a notification, you should see activity in the device console via Xcode's Organizer window.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it, but then the app wont be in a state of "not running". The app will have a state of "background" or "suspended" according to the apple docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html So then the apple documentation is fawlty. The app will not be notified and launched from all states.

Comment: It won't be running if you stop it from Xcode. Then when you send a remote notification, iOS launches the app in the background. Put some logging in your `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and remote notification handler.

Comment: Yes, well the point is that the feature is not at all so useful as it seems. And the documentation is deficient, at best. For instance, if the phone reboots, the app wont receive remote push notifications. And, from what i've learned now, the app wont receive remote push if the user kills the app (which i guess a lot of users do). If a user kills the app, there is no way to notify the user via a local push either that the app wont receive remote push.

Comment: @DavidCaunt If we stop app from xcode, the app will be in "suspended" state. Myself and Trj are saying that remote-notification is working only when the app is background/foreground/suspended state.  Thats why  Trj saying that apple doc is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 Background Fetch by Push Notification - Will iOS launch my app if it is not in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/ios-7-background-fetch-by-push-notification-will-ios-launch-my-app-if-it-is-no)

Comment: To enable background remote notification: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27816850/1603234

Answer (score 0):

Apple doc is a little confusing when it comes to remote notifications.
If your app was terminated by the user, or your device was rebooted, the notification won't be delivered.

> "content-available" only wakes up your app if it was in background, or
>   the app was killed by the system due to memory pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Adding/updating documentation, since I agree completely with Guatam Jain.  The force quit is what threw me--Apple can't tell the difference between a developer doing testing and a user "cleaning up their phone" or manhandling a misbehaving app.

From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html, section titled "Understanding When Your App Gets Launched into the Background" (emphasis mine):

> Apps that support background execution may be relaunched by the system to handle incoming events. If an app is terminated for any reason other than the user **force quitting** it, the system launches the app when one of the following events happens:
>   ...
>   For background download apps:
>   A push notification arrives for an app and the payload of the notification contains the content-available key with a value of 1.