# iOS equivalent for Android BOOT_COMPLETED and ACTION_SHUTDOWN

Tags: android, ios

In an Android application the app can "listen" to [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) and [ACTION_SHUTDOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN) events.

Is that possible under iOS? 
If it is - how can iOS app listen to those events?

Comment: You [cannot do this on boot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20086364/264775).

Comment: what about shutdown? Can I register a 'callback' for shutdown?

Comment: NO, apple now allow this

Comment: Dekel - can you please explain what do you mean by "NO, apple now allow this". Are you talking about boot or shutdown? Please explain how an application can register a callback to a boot / shutdown event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application lifecycle and application states on iOS are described in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3)

Essentially there are notifications for your app starting, moving to the background, moving back to the foreground and terminating (there are also some background execution modes) but as Dekel said in comments, an app doesn't receive any direct notifications that the device is shutting down or was restarted.

[image]