# Proper use of "content-available" in iOS 7 Push Notifications

Tags: ios, ios7, apple-push-notifications

I'm just looking for some feedback on my thought process surrounding iOS 7 and the "content-available" key value in a push notification payload.

Scenario:
I force shut down the application. According to Apple because I've done this I will no longer receive any notifications that contain the key value "content-available" in their payload. This means that the alert doesn't show at all, basically nothing happens. No sounds, no alert message, no badge increment.

Theory:
Because of the above scenario it seems as if you'd want to send two push notifications.

1. A push notification with just your "alert","badge" and "sound" values so that the user sees a notification related to the update irregardless of the application state.
2. A push notification with just the "content-available" key value. If the app is in a state where it can accept this it does and your background task is performed. In the case it can't accept it the user still receives a visual / audible notification from the first push notification.

Question:
Is this how Apple intends the silent / background notifications to be executed? I don't really see another way that you could implement this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 Background Fetch - Will iOS launch my app into the background if it was force-quit by the user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/ios-7-background-fetch-will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-fo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your thought process is right and the information you have is correct *for the current implementation of push notifications in iOS 7.0*

However  people have been filing bug reports and talking about the fact that forcibly quitting the app makes it ineligible to be woken up by a push notification with "content-available" in the payload (See [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19202487/1374512)). Hopefully Apple will address this in iOS 7.1 or at least update the docs.

Comment: Did apple changed the behaviour regarding the issue?

Comment: @YaronLevi As per the SO answer referenced in my answer, iOS 8 has not changed this.