# Which method will be triggered for pushnotification when app is in background?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented push notification in my App. When App is in foreground `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is get called. But when app is in background this method is not called. Following pattern is used in server side:

```
{ 
  aps: {
          content-available: 1,
          sound: "default"
       }
}
```

But still the didReceiveRemoteNotification is not get called. What else is to be done to get triggered the method after push notification arrives.

Comment: Is there user interaction with push notification ? or your app just sits and waiting in background ?

Comment: Please note that until any user interaction is performed, no method will be called when the application is in minimised state.

Comment: I guess you are talking about `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` method.

Comment: @JanakNirmal No App simply sits in background. Method is called when we tap notification alert on device banner. but i am asking the situation when there is no user interaction.

Comment: @OhhMee how can we perform any task in the App's minimised state?

Comment: We don't have much control over the app when it is at minimised state and absolutely no control over it when we receive a push and the application under minimised state. We need user interaction in your particular case.

Comment: @JansonThomas What exactly are you looking to execute when the application is at background state?

Comment: You don't have access to push notification until and unless the user explicitly opens up with tapping it or just open application and push notification was there in the queue for your app. You can check new iOS7 feature [Check this for further help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/ios-7-background-fetch-by-push-notification-will-ios-launch-my-app-if-it-is-no)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19068762/2446155

Answer (score 3):

There's a new API available to handle background events when the device receives a push notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

Now, as per the documentation:

> Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is
>   called only when your app is running, the system calls this method
>   regardless of the state of your app. If your app is suspended or not
>   running, the system wakes up or launches your app and puts it into the
>   background running state before calling the method.
>
> When this method is called, your app has up to 30 seconds of
>   wall-clock time to perform the download operation and call the
>   specified completion handler block. In practice, your app should call
>   the handler block as soon as possible after downloading the needed
>   data. If you do not call the handler in time, your app is suspended.
>   More importantly, the system uses the elapsed time to calculate power
>   usage and data costs for your app’s background downloads.

To trigger this method, you notification payload must contain a key `content-available`:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1
    },
    "content-id" : 42
}
```

Example Code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Remote Notification userInfo is %@", userInfo);

    NSNumber *contentID = userInfo[@"content-id"];
    // Do something with the content ID
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Comment: Note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/ios-7-background-fetch-by-push-notification-will-ios-launch-my-app-if-it-is-no/19202487#19202487

Comment: @SantaClaus +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 2):

didReceiveRemoteNotification method will be called when push notification arrives in app active state. 
If app is inactive when push notification arrived, an option to invoke didReceiveRemoteNotification method is to click on the received notification from notification list and become active.
If app is inactive when push notification arrived and become active by without clicking on notification received, normally there is no way to invoke didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

If you app needs, you can handle it by custom server. Whenever app becomes active, API call can be implemented to list pending notifications.

Answer (score 0):

This would be called:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

Check the `launchOptions`:

```
  NSDictionary *pushInformation = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
  if(pushInformation)
  {
    // App opened with push notification
  }
```

Comment: No. this method is not called when app is in background.

Comment: @JackyBoy I believe your answer is wrong. The link you provided states the same.

Comment: @JansonThomas you have two places to check it: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Comment: @JackyBoy `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will NOT be called if your app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` Will be called if your app is in `UIApplicationStateActive`

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` will be called if your app is in`UIApplicationStateBackground` or  `UIApplicationStateInactive` and the user opened a push notification from the notification center.

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be called upon launch if app was not in the background.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
       //Your Code here
    }
    else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```