# UINotification ios not received when app is in background

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am using notification in one of my app ,when app is active , notification is received , i process data and everything is fine , but I do not receive any notification when app is in background or killed.What is the issue can any one plz help me ?

Thank you!

Here is what I doing so far

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    tokenstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];

    tokenstring = [tokenstring stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    tokenstring = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[tokenstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]];
    NSLog(@"TokeinID:>> %@",tokenstring);


}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification: %@",userInfo);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1002);

    //Some code or logic
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@",err.description);



}
```

Comment: What payload are you getting when device receive push notification?

Comment: If your app is in background, and Notification is come  it shows in notification center, when user tap on that notification then `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is called.

Comment: Hi Aman there was problem with Payload , Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you receive remote notifications, `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is only called when your app is in the foreground. If your app is in the background or terminated, then the OS may display an alert or play a sound (depending on the aps dictionary in the notification), but the delegate method is not called.

The remote notification received in the background will only passed to your application if it is launched with that notification's action button, and then you need to look at the launch options dictionary on `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to see the content of the notification.

If you're looking at new content fetching/remote notification background support with iOS7, check [Will iOS launch my app into the background if it was force-quit by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/ios-7-background-fetch-by-push-notification-will-ios-launch-my-app-if-it-is-no) and see if that helps, as there are very specific circumstances that those functions work in.

Answer (score 1):

little code ..

When app is not running

> (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
>   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

is called  ..

where u need to check for push notification

```
 UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if (notification) {
    NSLog(@"app recieved notification from remote%@",notification);
    [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)notification];
}else{
 }
```