# Receiving push notifications in background iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, background, push-notification

I'm working on an app that receives push notifications from Zenpush service. I managed to set up both app and account on Zenpush to sent and receive notifications.

When the app is active (opened) and I receive notification - everything is OK. I handle this in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`.

Also, I can handle notification when user taps on it when it arrives, or opens app from the notification center.

The issue is - I can't handle notifications if the app is in the background, or terminated.
I've been struggling with this for a week now. 
I have both **Background fetch** and **Remote notifications** enabled in **Background modes**.
In Scheme I checked "Launch due to background fetch event".
According to Apple documentation and what I've found on StackOverflow I'm using following method to handle notifications in the background: `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`.

No matter what i send in notification, this method is not called. I tried to determine this by making changes to some data, and trying to NSLog something.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/873265#873265

I include "content-available": 1 in my notifications.

Is there something else I'm missing? Or maybe there is a way  to get all notifications that was receiver while app was in background/terminated where the app becomes active?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19068762/2446155

Comment: You should be able to handle notifications through that method when the app is in the *background*, just not when it is *terminated* (by swiping up in app switcher)

Comment: @SantaClaus I've tried using the code in the related question that you mentioned. But the app still not reacting to notification.

Comment: Try *unchecking* "Launch due to background fetch event" in your Scheme. This is a debug feature meant to simulate launching due to a background fetch, but you want to test using a normal launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stil not being able to get app to call `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`
I decided to debug what exactly i receive from Zenpush.
Turns out, using their Custom Payload section to add `content-available` is not the right way to do it. 
This way `content-available` is added after `asp` object, not inside of it.

I wrote to Zenpush support about it, if i get any info on how to send `content-available` inside `asp` i will edit this answer

## Update:

I got the response from Zenpush support. This feature is tested now, and will be available soon.

## Update 2:

Zenpush added a checkbox for background services, and now it works just fine.
[image]

Comment: i am also working with the same scenario but i am using FCM . i am also stuck like you that i could not open push notification until i tap on the notification message . do you have any idea regarding how to solve this with FCM ?