# Why does my iphone app not receive background fetch events after being terminated?

Tags: ios, iphone, termination, application-lifecycle, background-foreground

I've built a small ios app which perform periodic updates.
I'm registering my app for **background fetches** with a callback handler.
When app goes background I'm continue to receive callbacks over the time (every 20-30 minutes, event days later).

Once my app is **terminated** - the callback handler will be not executed any more.

Is it excepted behavior? I failed to find any mentions about activation from terminated state in Apple documentation on this.

ps: activation from the **terminated** state is crucial for my app. The approach of the activation could be any, except of user interaction.

Comment: Maybe this will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/ios-7-background-fetch-by-push-notification-will-ios-launch-my-app-if-it-is-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if an app is terminated it will be awaken neither by background fetch nor push notification. No official documentation on this though.

> Also keep in mind that if you kill your app from the app switcher
>   (i.e. swiping up to kill the app) then the OS will never relaunch the
>   app regardless of push notification or background fetch.  In this case
>   the user has to manually relaunch the app once and then from that
>   point forward the background activities will be invoked.

Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/ios-7-background-fetch-by-push-notification-will-ios-launch-my-app-if-it-is-no)