# Is there any way for an iOS app to retrieve updates or make a web service call while not running?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an iOS 7+ app and was wondering if there was a way for an app that wasn't running (i.e. not running in the background but completely killed) to start running and perform a function such as a web service call. I am aware of mechanisms such as background fetch and core location being able to send events to an app while in the background (but still running/suspended).  Is there such a way to send events to an app that is not running?

I know the answer is probably no, but I need to confirm it.

Comment: If app is killed how do you expect it to execute some code written in it?

Comment: This seems like a silly question. If the app has been completely killed not running in background or anything how would you expect it to do anything?

Comment: I knew the answer was probably "no" (as stated in my question) but wanted to make sure that no one had a workaround or something "hacky".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `NO`.

Background Fetches will only work after the iOS starts and will stop working once the user force-closes the application.  The same is true for Silent Push notifications and Location services.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user) explains the details.