# Objective-C keep running app in background

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

is  `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` capable of making calculations every day at 10AM, even when app is closed complitly (killed with task manager).

Sorry for stupid question but I don't want to start making something pointless. :)

Comment: You need to search for "push notifications".  Some details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user) to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of. You can implement background fetching for your app in this method

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

However, you can't just implement the method. You have to be sure to enable background fetching for your application. [Background fetching](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56)

Note that you can choose one of two options

1: Have the iOS schedule the fetch for you based on when the user usually opens your app

2: Request a time interval between fetches. Not guaranteed to execute when you want though, just a request.