# Roll Back Push Notifications in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I just saw a functionality used by [Inbox by Gmail](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fin%2Fapp%2Finbox-by-gmail-inbox-that%2Fid905060486%3Fmt%3D8&ei=B3XkVO_2NJK3uQS30oLIAw&usg=AFQjCNGER4yrdJiF5QM2W8X9LJwNVDsgbw&sig2=LkL74953EULwxG6A3Jt4HQ&bvm=bv.85970519,d.c2E&cad=rja) app.Scenario is like this:-
When any mail arrives,the application get Push Notification for the mails..Now don't open the app in iphone,Open [Inbox website](https://inbox.google.com) and login over the website with the same account,Now read those mails for which the notifications arrived in iphone.

As soon as you read the mails over the website,the notifications would got disappear from the phone.I am just curious to know aboust how's it possible even the app isn't in Background state.

**I know you guys may vote down for this question but think about it before going to vote.**

Comment: Not sure if it helps or not : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551108/dismissing-ios-push-notifications-remotely?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Can be with silent push notification, in the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` you can remote your notification with the `[application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeNumber - 1];`

Comment: application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler also needs the launch of app first,they are doing this even without launching the app.

Comment: No, application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: is called regardless of app state.If app is suspended or not running, then the system wakes up or launches your app and puts it into the background running state before calling the method.