# iOS: use VOiP notification instead of "normal" notif

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, pushkit

We just add VOiP capability to our app (messaging app), now we will use VOiP ([PushKit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/PushKit_Framework/index.html)).

Can anyone tell me if we can use only that notifications (VOIP notifications)? Meaning even for text message for example (not for a call)? I talk about Apple Appstore Guides, they can reject the app or block the notifications if they found that we use that notification to notify the user about other things then a VOIP call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes, i used the VOiP notification for a no-voip notifications (like a text message) and Apple accept the app (and i can can confirm, after some tests, that whatsapp use the same thing as my app).

Comment: Is your app uploaded on app store? Can you tell more about functionality of your app? As far as I know, Apple doesn't allow PushKit notifications without implementing VOIP functionality in app.

Comment: My app is a messassing app, if you read my question i say that it have VOiP feature but my problem was that the documetation is not cleare about using PushKit to send/receive other notifications then voip notif (like incoming calls) like a text message, my app is accepted and for ios 8 and highrt we only use PushKit for all kind of notifications.

Comment: Whatsapp doesn't use VOIP ( Silent notification ) to receive message while app is in killed or background state, they use XMPP server,

Comment: what ? im not talking about how they deliver the information, im talking about how they notify user .. oh and XMPP, SIP, .. will not awake an app ..

Comment: @RedMak. we are implementing messaging and other(confidential) data through puskit VoIP. 

-How can i assure that my build with pass through app review?

Comment: @RedMak Remote notification have draw back. when user is not connected with internet and push notification scenario occurs(like 5 push were sent to device A). APNS only sent last notification and it doesn't awake the app.

Comment: @AlizainPrasla i didn’t understand your first quedtion, for the second one: this is not true, ios will awake your app so even if you only receive the last notif (which i doubt) you can connect to your server and display local notifications for each message.

Comment: @RedMak Pushkit awakes the app, normal remote notification don't awake the app. right?

Comment: my 1st questions. in app, we don't have any voip functionality. all we have is messaging and other data which we pass through puskit. how can i assure that app store reviewer don't reject the build?

Comment: @AlizainPrasla 1. Yes normal notif do not awake the app BUT a special type is silent notification (google it) can awake your app (with some conditions).   2. VOIP notification can ONLY be used in voip apps, if you didn’t have voip do not take the risk ! Apple WILL reject your app (if not the first version it will be rejected later)

Comment: @RedMak 
1-Does silent notification awake app in terminated state? 
2-We are using messaging functionality. does that reason is enough for app store to pass the build?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191987/discussion-between-alizain-prasla-and-red-mak).

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement VOIP functionality in order to not to be rejected. I've tried to use it for messages between users and it was not approved. So if you really don't have VOIP functionality, modify your server to your needs.

Comment: thanks for your answer but as i say have VOiP functionality.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought you added VOIP for standard messages. I would still recommend using normal notifications for text messages.

Answer (score 1):

I have also implemented VOIP push notification in our app. But app is rejected by app store by saying 
"We continue to find that your app declares support for VoIP in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but it does not include any Voice over IP services.

Please revise your app to either add VoIP features or remove the "voip" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.

We recognize that VoIP can provide "keep alive" functionality that is useful for many app features. However, using VoIP in this manner is not the intended purpose of VoIP.".

Comment: You can put your app in particular category and contact apple to allow for pushkit usage due to so and so reason.

Comment: Hi @Hasya . How would that work? Have you done this before? I am developing an app that is supposed to notify a user of imminent danger but that does not offer any VoIP feature. So using VoIP pushes to deliver high priority notifications and even launching a terminated app would be ideal in case of emergency.

Comment: Hi @Maarten. Yes as per your description that works. Even without launching a teenaged app. Please refer further https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification