# iOS Silent Notification that displays banner and wakes app to run some background code?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I've been trying to implement the following scenario:

> When an event is cancelled, send a push notification to all devices
> that were subscribed to that event in order to remove the already queued
> local notification for the event's starting time.

Think of it as a calendar. If an event gets cancelled, no local notification should be displayed on the devices when the event's starting time comes.

I've been trying to send a silent(background) push notification to the iOS devices which will do two things:

1. display the notification banner (saying something like *The event "X" was cancelled*)
2. wake up the terminated app to run some code (remove the queued local alert that was supposed to fire on the event's starting time)

but I could not make it work **when the application is terminated**.

I've checked the "Remote notifications" option in the Background Modes of the app's Capabilities, implemented the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` method in `AppDelegate` and I've sent the following payload:

```
{
   aps: {
            alert: @message,
            sound: 'default',
            badge: 1,
            'content-available' => 1
   },
   objectId: 1,
   type: 'removed'
}
```

I've also included the header fields:

```
apns-push-type = BACKGROUND
apns-priority = 5
```

The `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` is called only when the app is in FOREGROUND or BACKGROUND, but not when it is INACTIVE (killed, closed, terminated via app switcher...)

Is it possible to achieve the behaviour that I want?
Note: I'm using ios 13.5.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOS notification when Application is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057772/ios-notification-when-application-is-closed)

Comment: TL;DR from the duplicate: It's normal behavior. iOS will not run any code from your app if it was closed by the user. Same goes for geofences.

Comment: @QuentinHayot what is says is that didReceiveRemoteNotification method will not get called when the application is closed, but would there be any other way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: @LalKrishna do you mean PushKit's voip notifications? If so, aren't they  a reason to get your app rejected from the store if used this way?

Comment: Sorry. We can't use PushKit if the app doesn't support VoiP calls. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58162829/4061501

Comment: When a device receives a background notification, the system may hold and delay the delivery of the notification, which may cause Notification discard by the system if something force quits or kills the app. [Read more](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app)