# Push not executing while app is closed IOS

Tags: ios, push-notification

I use push notifications but while my app is closed,and push received it is not executed(i perceived by putting break point didreceived method),only appears on screen.What can i do to detect push received while app is closed?
I use also background fetch and remote notifications in target->Capabilities

MY Codes :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)   (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
```

Comment: Your app won't be woken up, if it was force-quit by the user, there is no way to achieve this with push notifications at the moment. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user?lq=1) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31514104/594074).

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to set "content-available" to 1 in the notification body.

2) And have the right background modes: [Background Modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22)

Also: Your users can turn this off by disabling Background App Refresh in the iPhone Settings. You can check this in code:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundRefreshStatus!=UIBackgroundRefreshStatusAvailable
```

Comment: I still use content-available" = 1,and background modes.

Comment: in background mode it is working no problem,but in closed..not working. @ nils ziehn

Comment: Oh, now I understand: your problem is that after 'manually' closing the app, apple won't call your app.

Comment: But if the user just restarts the phone, you app will be started for instance.