# iOS UILocalNotification only makes a sound (no alert) when app is not running

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm using remote notifications to wake up my app and conditionally trigger a UILocalNotification.

I've found that if this notification is triggered while the app is not running, all I get is the notification sound (no alert/notification).  It works as expected if the app is in the background.

Registering for remote notifications in AppDelegate:

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: (.Badge | .Sound | .Alert), categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Creating/Firing of UILocalNotification (as a result of `didReceiveRemoteNotification`)

```
var notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertTitle = "My App"
notification.alertBody = "Hello World!"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
```

As far as I can tell from the documentation, notification behavior when the app is in the background and simply not running should be the same..

> When the system delivers a local notification, several things can happen, depending on the app state and the type of notification. If the app is not frontmost and visible, the system displays the alert message, badges the app, and plays a sound—whatever is specified in the notification. If the notification is an alert and the user taps the action button (or, if the device is locked, drags open the action slider), the app is woken up or launched.

Source: [UILocalNotification Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html)

Insight into what's going on here is much appreciated!

Comment: Run the Settings app and go to the page for your app. Check the notification settings for your app.

Comment: I've verified notification settings for the app are enabled. As I mentioned, it all works as expected when the app is in the background, but not when I explicitly close it (by swiping it away)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the display of local notifications.

As you said in your question, you use remote notifications to TRIGGER opening your app and then run code to conditionally show a local notification.

The reason why this is not working is:

Your code to show a local notification is **NOT** run from remote notifications after the user has force closed the app (by swipe up)!

You can find more on this in the developer forums here:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/873265#873265 (dev account login requiered)

> Also keep in mind that if you kill your app from the app switcher (i.e. swiping up to kill the app) then the OS will **never relaunch the app regardless of push notification or background fetch**.  In this case the user has to manually relaunch the app once and then from that point forward the background activities will be invoked.

Comment: Thanks, this does appear to be the case.  It seems I should move my decision point on what notification to show to my web server to ensure reliable notifications.

More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user