# How to ensure users continue to receive push notifications even if they have force-quit the app?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Apple's [remote notifications programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1) says this:

> On an iOS device, if a user force-quits your app using the app
> multitasking UI, the app does not receive remote notifications until
> the user relaunches it.

But I am certain that when I force-quit Facebook, WhatsApp or Signal, I still receive notifications about incoming messages.

How do they pull that off even though Apple says that's not possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push Notification code execution (forced-quit app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016616/push-notification-code-execution-forced-quit-app)

Comment: If the remote notification contains an alert payload, ios will still display this.  Your app just can't receive silent push notifications.  If your app is a VoIP app then you can use a VoIP push to relaunch your app but your app must then report an incoming call to CallKit or it will be terminated.

Comment: Great, yes that answers it.