# Return app to background for bluetooth event handling after manual app termination

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm implementing a programmable BLE button. I've managed to implement the
scenario when the app is terminated by the system and then when I press the
button the bluetooth central manager restores its state with the `centralManager(_:willRestoreState:):`
method. The peripheral is connected and all the services are visible. But this happens only after I
emulate the app termination via `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL)`.

But. When I terminated the app via double clicking the Home button and swiping the app off the screen
the `centralManager(_:willRestoreState:):` is not called and the app is not returned to the background.

Why is that? It turns out that termination of an app with the ios itself and the manual termination 
of an app are different things.

So how can I make so that the app is returned to background not only after ios app termination but
also after manual termination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is desired behaviour. IMO there is no way to work around. If user swipe up your application in the app switcher, that means that he/she don't wont to be bothering by app anymore. This is Apple way to respect user's privacy.

The [same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user) with remote notifications.