# Does the OS wake up the app on receiving the remote notification?

Tags: ios, notifications

Is there a way to wake up the app on receiving remote notifications?

If I delete the app from app preview, I don't get the remote notification. On getting the notification I have to download few images.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Which images You have downloaded?

Comment: If you terminate the app from the app switcher by swiping up then the app will not be relaunched in the background until the user launches the app again from the app icon or a notification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will iOS launch my app into the background if it was force-quit by the user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the [`content-available`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) key in your payload:

> Provide this key with a value of 1 to indicate that new content is
>   available. Including this key and value means that when your app is
>   launched in the background or resumed,
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: is
>   called.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your target's launch settings in "Manage Scheme" to `Wait for <app>.app to be launched manually`, which allows you debug by setting a breakpoint in `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:` and sending the push notification to trigger the background launch.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification is not getting called when notification is sent from server while the app is in background. When the app is in foreground the function gets called. But why is it not getting called in background? I have tested by inserting a value to database in didReceiveRemoteNotification function. Value is not getting inserted. How do I make this work? Please help