# Silent remote notification if app is terminated in iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, silent

When I get a remote notification I need to perform segue.This process is happening perfectly in background. But if the app is terminated/ killed by sliding up in app preview then I am not getting the notification. Actually it is a silent notification and user cannot see it. So the user has no way to launch the app in foreground on receiving the notification. How do I handle this situation?

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19202487/4062250

Comment: @Smita how u handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

APNS is handled by the operating system which will not notify you app if it's not foregrounded or running in the background. Apple has specific regulations on how what applications can have extended background processes  here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Regardless, once the app is terminated APNS will not start the application. A user must start the application either by tapping the icon or interacting with the notification.