# How to start application in background while app is in inactive state

Tags: ios

I wants to start my app in background state while app is not in active state using local notification.
Is it possible? if yes then please guide me.

Comment: Huh?  You want to start the app in background state when it's already in background state?

Comment: No, i wants to start app in background when app is neither in active nor in background state. app is terminated and when app receives local notification it should be started in background.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just start an app in the background unless you give it a specific task with a finite result. There are few scenarios where this is a valid thing to do.
All is very well documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)