# How to download data while app is not running (app is killed)

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to download data in background even when app is not running. Is it possible?
I have tried using background fetch but it is not working.
Please refer to the code below:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 9
}
```

It gets called when app is running but not when app is killed

Comment: If the user terminates your app then it doesnt execute until the user relaunches it (there is an exception for VoIP push and location geofence entry).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will iOS launch my app into the background if it was force-quit by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user)

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application#discussion. which states: However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately background fetch works for max 3 min after the app is deactivated or in the background. Except for VOIP, Location, Audio..ect

What you can do is send a remote push notification *"according to a certain event taking place in your backend server"* to your App so the user interacts with it and gets your app to the foreground.

As soon as the app is loaded to the foreground you can add an observer with a selector function in `viewWillAppear` to start fetching the data you need.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```

Selector function:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ notification: NSNotification) {

    print("Fetch data")

}
```

Then in `viewWillDisappear` remove the observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```