# IOS notification when Application is closed

Tags: ios, push-notification, apn, remote-notifications

i have a ios application where to which i send remote notification when sending notification from server i am setting **content -available = 1** and **sound = ""** 
When on IOS device i am using

> applicaiton(didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)

I seeing that app reaches this method when in background but when app is closed this method is not getting called But is not getting called when application is closed

> applicaiton(didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)

My handler in this method is

```
        let userInfoDic = userInfo as NSDictionary as? [String: Any]
        let cato = userInfoDic?["cato"] as? String
if cato == "message" {
            let state: UIApplicationState = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
            if state == .active{
                print("Application is Active Socket IO will Handle This")
            }else{
                let apnMessage = userInfoDic?["apnMessage"] as? [String: Any]
                if (apnMessage == nil){
                    print("Error Fetching Message")
                }else{
                let count = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey:"TotalUnredMessage")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = count + 1
                    }
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(count, forKey: "TotalUnredMessage")
          }
}
```

So what should i change for this methods to run even when applicaiton is closed

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**didReceiveRemoteNotification** method will not call when the application is closed.

But you can check **launchOptions** to know weather the application has been launched from notification or not in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method in appdelegate and do your task accordingly.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

     if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil {
    // Do your task here
    }

}
```

Comment: What will happen if the user directly taps the app icon and not come through notification or will i be able to see all the notification received when application was closed
Thanks for the answer

Comment: if the user does not open the app by tapping the notification, there is no way to get the notification information. In that case you have to check with your server for unread notifications.

Comment: My whole requirement is to increment the badge count I tried sending +1 in badge i does not work

Comment: Push notifications are handled by iOS and in your app you can't change the application badge on receiving a push notification when the application is closed. But you can calculate the badge number and send the badge number in the payload of the push notification from your server.

Comment: can we get userInfo here??

Answer (score 3):

To complete Prakash Shaiva by showing how to retrieve the notification userIn **didFinishWithLaunchOptions**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

     if let launchOptions = launchOptions,
            let userInfo =  launchOptions[.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {
            //some code here and post when needed like below
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("your notification name"),  object: nil)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify in configuration, that your app needs be waked on remote  notification.
Check this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29231395/2732896