# Can we access app when it is terminated/kill from background in ios 10

Tags: ios, process, terminate

Can we access app when it is terminated/kill from background in ios 10.Actually i want to fetch lat long to hit the api when app is terminated from background.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? When a user closes an app running in the background, they want it to close.

Comment: As my app contains the cards if the user fall in between 500mtr from the place of card then a notifications falls.So i want user app is in background or terminated from background location will update?? hope you understand my point.

Comment: @NickA he simply want to do this because he need to. For instance, need to update the app with a new data that the user might want to know about even if he accidently closed the app.

Answer (score 0):

No. When the user terminates your app, the systems stops executing any code you were running in your app and you cannot manually restart your app.

The only way your app can be started after the user has killed it is by using the `PushKit` framework and receiving a push notification from your server. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29231395/4667835) answer. However, this framework was designed for VoIP applications and in your scenario the server doesn't know when to send the information, so even using `PushKit` wouldn't solve your problem.