# Linphone(3.16.3) ios app push notification not working when app is killed

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, voip, linphone

I am using linphone open source app (ver 3.16.3) to make video call in my

application. PushKit is already embeded in this version of linephone app.

So, I get iOS device notifications when app is minimized or running in

the foreground. But, iOS device notifications are not working when I kill

the app. This is working fine for linphone's app which I downloaded from

appstore.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Note : I have created VOIP certificate for this app.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user/29231395#29231395) SO question?

Comment: I already implemented PushKit. This is an issue of the last update of the source code of Linphone. If I reinstall the previous source code, the push notifications will work fine. But the app gives some other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I edited the didBecomeActive. I forced start_at_boot to NO, because I thought that with push notifications we don't need to boot the app when we switch on the phone.