# Push notifications to wake background app

Tags: swift, push-notification, background, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to have my app execute functions in the background on a regular basis. As `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` is too unpredictable I read about APNs.

Can I use APNs to periodically send a silent push notification to the device that would make the app execute my data fetching and analyzing functions then displaying a notification to the user accordingly?

Is it possible to have the server send the "wakeup signal" only and have the app display the notification by itself because of this?

I might have misunderstood the APNs logic entirely.

Comment: Sounds sneaky, so Apple probably wouldn't like it.

Comment: Maybe this question and answers may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19202487/4597019

Comment: Thanks Jack but my app is not a VoIP so it might get rejected if i use PushKit but it seemed to be a great solution. I'm amazed at how hard it is to only have my app refreshed on a regular basis in the background. Could I use the API I'm fetching the data from to trigger the refreshing process when it's data is updated through APNs? I thought `content-available` was my solution.