# Detecting an actionable notification button when launching app from force quit - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications

Here is my situation:

- I have an app that gives the user a notification every hour.
- This notification is actionable, with a "Mute Until Tomorrow" button attached to it. This button is, as you might guess, supposed to reschedule notifications to begin again the next day.
- Thus, I have a block of code that needs to execute when you press this button.

If the app is running in the background, I use this function in my FirstViewController.swift file:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

If the app is running in the background, this works perfectly. However, if the app has been force-quit by the user, this does not work. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19202487/7332288), <strike>iOS will never relaunch the app after the user force quits it.</strike> Edit: Apparently pressing a button in an actionable notification counts as user interaction, and your app *can* run code in response to this.

So I changed my actionable notification button to bring the app into the foreground when it is pressed, thinking this would solve my issue. However, for some reason, the function above is *not* called when launching the app from the button when the app has been force closed.

My first thought was to fix this using this function in the AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

but based on [this list of launch option keys from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/launch_options_keys), I don't see a key for "actionable notification button pressed" or anything similar to that.

**How do I detect that my app has been launched from an actionable notification button after it has been force closed?**

Update: According to [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter), "If you do not implement this method [the first one I've listed above], your app never responds to custom actions." If this is true and there is no other method that will catch this, what do I do? Is what I'm trying to do simply impossible?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I moved the method I was originally trying to use:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

from my `FirstViewController` to my `AppDelegate`. I also moved all the setup code:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
let muteAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "muteActionID", title: "Mute until tomorrow", options: [])
let tutorialCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "muteCategory", actions: [muteAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([tutorialCategory])
```

to the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. The `didReceive response` method is now called when I press the actionable notification button, regardless of whether or not the app has been force closed or not. **Better still, it even works without having the open the app in the foreground.**

Comment: Works really well. Thank you